# React Native Picker ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeception

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, picker

I am using [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) component from React Native.

I have two Picker components: `State` (`stateList() function`) and `City` (`cityList() function`). I am calling two APIs: `apiState()` function loads the list of `State` and based on the State selected, the `apiCity(state_identification)` function will display a list of `City`. (*code snippet provided below*)

**Code Snippet**:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pickerValueState: null,
        dataState: [],

        pickerValueCity: null,
        dataCity: [],

        isLoading: true,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.apiState();
}

apiState() {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_c/cState/',
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Response State Data: ', response.data.state);
                self.setState({
                    dataState: response.data.state,
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error (1st): ', error);
            });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error (2nd): ', error) //Display error
    });
}

apiCity(state_identification) {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_c/cCity/',
            data: {
                state_id: state_identification,
            },
            /*params: {
                state_id: state_identification,
            },*/
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Response City Data: ', response.data.all_city);
                self.setState({
                    pickerValueState: state_identification,
                    dataCity: response.data.all_city,
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error (1st): ', error);
            });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error (2nd): ', error) //Display error
    });
}

stateList() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text h4 h4Style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Select Location</Text>
            <Text h4 h4Style={styles.location}>State</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
                <Picker
                    mode="dropdown"
                    selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueState}
                    //onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue })}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        /*this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue },
                            () => {
                                this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState, itemValue);
                                console.log('State selected: ', (this.state.pickerValueState))
                            }
                        )*/
                        this.apiCity(itemValue)
                    }}
                >
                    {
                        this.state.dataState.map((item, key) => (
                            <Picker.Item label={item.state_desc} value={item.state} key={key} />)
                        )
                    }
                </Picker>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

cityList() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text h4 h4Style={styles.location}>City</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
                <Picker
                    mode="dropdown"
                    selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueCity}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        this.setState({ pickerValueCity: itemValue },
                            () => {
                                console.log('City selected: ', (this.state.pickerValueCity))
                            }
                        )
                    }}
                >
                    {
                        this.state.dataCity.map((item, key) => (
                            <Picker.Item label={item.city_desc} value={item.city} key={key} />)
                        )
                    }
                </Picker>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
                    {this.stateList()}
                    {this.cityList()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
}
```

**Before I continue here's what the JSON data and the relation between `State` and `City` looks like:**

```
//Lists of states:

{
    "state": [
        {
            "state": "14",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "state": "10",
            "state_desc": "Selangor"
        }
    ]
}

//if "state":"14" is selected, these cities are rendered in the picker
{
    "all_city": [
        {
            "city": "262",
            "city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "263",
            "city_desc": "Sungai Besi"
        }
    ]
}

//if "state":"10" is selected, these cities are rendered in the picker
{
    "all_city": [
        {
            "city": "256",
            "city_desc": "Puchong"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I am facing several issues with my code and these are:**

> **1. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeception: length=1;index=1 (*screenshot provided below*):**
>
> By following this sequence the app crashes 100% of the time:
>
> - select `"state":"10"`
> - then change to select `"state":"14"` and `"city":"263"`
> - then finally select `"state":"10"` again
>
> the app immediately crashes.

[image]

> **2. Problem with loading values**:
>
> When the app initially loads, `"state": "14"` is auto-selected BUT the `City` picker remains empty / doesn't display the label.
>
> Then if I select `"state":"10"`, the `City` picker loads the value `"city": "256"` ( and shows the value on the console.log) and it displays the label `"city_desc": "Puchong"`.
>
> However, when I select `"state": "14"` again, the `City` picker doesn't load the value (doesn't show the value on the console.log) but only displays the label `"city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"`. It only starts loading the value once I start interchanging between `"city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"` and `"city_desc": "Sungai Besi"`
>
> FINALLY, when I select `"state":"10"` AGAIN, the `City` picker doesn't load the value (doesn't show the value on the console.log) but only displays the label `"city_desc": "Puchong"`.

**Lastly,** I have tried the following [solution](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/204)(*i.e `key={item.length}`*) from here but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

with this:

```
 this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue },
                        () => {
                            this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState);
                            console.log('State selected: ', (this.state.pickerValueState))
                        }
                    )
```

you have a period where the state have the new state, but the old city. which cause your exception. try to set state of the new `state` in the response of the `city` api. so you set the new state and new city at the same time. which probably mean you should pass to the `apiCity` function the new state as a parameter, then you use it in the api response.

So in the change event just do:

```
this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState, itemValue);
```

and in the `apiCityFunction`, after fetch in setState for both together - city and state:

```
 self.setState({
       pickerValueState: state,
       dataCity: response.data.all_city,
       isLoading: false,
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I kind of understood what you mean. But could you provide an example? It would be really helpful. Cheers.

Comment: in the picker change event: `this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState, itemValue);` then in the `apiCity` you receive the selected state as a parameter, and pass it after get response from the fetch. when you set the state: `self.setState({pickerValueState: state,
                    dataCity: response.data.all_city,
                    isLoading: false,
                });`

Comment: I just tried your workaround method but the issue still remains. I am still getting the both problems that I have mentioned.

Comment: Made the edit in the code snippet. please do check if this is what you meant.

Comment: Almost. you do good passing the `state` to the `cityApi`, but it should be instead setting the `state` before calling the `city Api`. instead `this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue },
                        () => {
                            this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState);
                        }
                    )` just 
                            `this.apiCity(this.state.pickerValueState);`

Comment: made the changes but still getting the same issues. Please check my latest Code Snippet. Also you can propose edit on my code as it will be easier for both of us to understand.

Comment: when you update the city list, I think you should also update the current city. since the choosen city from before not exist anymore. so `self.setState({
                    pickerValueState: state_identification,
                    dataCity: response.data.all_city,
                    picjkerValueCity: response.data.all_city[0],
                    isLoading: false,
                });`

Comment: about the second problem, - you cannot acpect the picker to auto select city, before its have a city list. but from `api_fetch` you get only the state list. you should call the `api_city` when get data from the `api_fetch`, and pass there the first state of the received list

Comment: Hi. I have made some few adjustments and created a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360160/react-native-arrayindexoutofboundsexeception). Do check it out.