# React Native ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

I am using [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) component from React Native.

I have two Picker components:

1. **`State` (`stateList() function`)**
2. **`City` (`cityList() function`)**

I am calling two APIs:

1. **`apiState() function`**: it loads the list of `State`
2. **`apiCity(state_identification) function`**: based on the `State` selected, this function will display a list of `City`

(*code snippet provided below*)

**Code Snippet**:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pickerValueState: null,
            dataState: [],

            pickerValueCity: null,
            dataCity: [],

            isLoading: true,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ComponentDidMount()')
        this.apiState();
    }

    apiState() {
        let self = this;
        AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_c/cState/',
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                    'Authorization': keyValue,
                },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('apiState() Success Response response.data.state: ', response.data.state);
                    self.setState({
                        dataState: response.data.state,
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error (1st): ', error);
                });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('Error (2nd): ', error) //Display error
        });
    }

    stateList() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text h4 h4Style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Select Location</Text>
                <Text h4 h4Style={styles.location}>State</Text>
                <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
                    <Picker
                        mode="dropdown"
                        selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueState}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue });
                            this.apiCity(itemValue);
                            console.log('State selected (itemValue): ', itemValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            this.state.dataState.map((item, key) => (
                                <Picker.Item label={item.state_desc} value={item.state} key={key} />)
                            )
                        }
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    apiCity(state_identification) {
        let self = this;
        AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_c/cCity/',
                data: {
                    state_id: state_identification,
                },
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                    'Authorization': keyValue,
                },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('apiCity() Success Response response.data.city: ', response.data.all_city);
                    self.setState({
                        pickerValueState: state_identification,
                        dataCity: response.data.all_city,
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error (1st): ', error);
                });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('Error (2nd): ', error) //Display error
        });
    }

    cityList() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text h4 h4Style={styles.location}>City</Text>
                <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
                    <Picker
                        mode="dropdown"
                        selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueCity}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ pickerValueCity: itemValue });
                            console.log('City selected (outside itemValue): ', itemValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            this.state.dataCity.map((item, key) => (
                                <Picker.Item label={item.city_desc} value={item.city} key={key} />)
                            )
                        }
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text h3 h3Style={styles.screenTitle}>BookingApp</Text>
                <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
                    {this.stateList()}
                    {this.cityList()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Before I continue here's what the JSON data and the relation between `State` and `City` looks like:**

```
//Lists of states:

{
    "state": [
        {
            "state": "14",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "state": "10",
            "state_desc": "Selangor"
        }
    ]
}

//if "state":"14" is selected, these cities are rendered in the picker
{
    "all_city": [
        {
            "city": "262",
            "city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "263",
            "city_desc": "Sungai Besi"
        }
    ]
}

//if "state":"10" is selected, these cities are rendered in the picker
{
    "all_city": [
        {
            "city": "256",
            "city_desc": "Puchong"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I am facing several issues with my code and these are:**

> **1. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeception: length=1;index=1 (*screenshot provided below*):**
>
> By following this sequence the app crashes 100% of the time:
>
> - select `"state":"14"` and `"city":"263"` ([something like this](https://prnt.sc/r6dx49))
> - then select `"state":"10"`
>
> as soon as `"state":"10"` is selected, the app will immediately crash and the following bug report is shown:

[image]

> **2. Problem with loading values**:
>
> 1. When the app initially loads, these are [auto-selected](https://prnt.sc/r6dxny): `"state": "14"` (State) and `"city": "262"` (City). Both the APIs gets called and the picker values for `State` and `City` gets [updated](https://prnt.sc/r6dvxm). Similarly, when I select `"city": "263"` ([sungai besi](https://prnt.sc/r6e1ti)), its picker value gets [updated](https://prnt.sc/r6e1i6) too.
> 2. However, when changes are made and the `State` is changed such as: `"state": "10"` and `"city": "256"` (the *city picker label* [auto-changes](https://prnt.sc/r6dzw3) as it should)... BUT the *City`picker value* ***doesn't*** get [updated][9] and only the`apiCity() function` is called.
> 3. Furthermore, when I change state again to: `"state": "14"` and `"city": "262"`(the *city picker label* [auto-changes](https://prnt.sc/r6e7yo) as it should)... BUT, ONCE AGAIN the *City picker value* ***doesn't*** get [updated](https://prnt.sc/r6e6g4) and only the `apiCity() function` is called.

**Lastly,** I have tried the following [solution](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/204)(*i.e `key={item.length}`*) but it didn't work.

Comment: brother, I will recommend using Flipper by the Facebook app to get the crash logs properly rather than depending on the emulator death screen! I see you are not using redux to handle data and are depending on component-based state approach! which will be putting pressure on UI thread

Comment: the crash is like some of your picker item selection is causing to access an array's index that does not exist, which crashes the whole application

Comment: you can use a try-catch, for now, to get the thing out of your head! and get the error log in flipper read it out! debug it!

Comment: @RizwanAtta brother, thank you for the suggestions. I am not so experienced with Redux thus I am following the 'normal' way for now. I will try and use Flipper for debugging. Lastly, where should I put the try-catch actually as I am confused if the problem is with my API call or if I have to change anything with Picker etc.

Comment: as API city is also going checking async function and also calls state change ( you should use setState callback to call the rest) like:

 this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue }, ()=>{this.apiCity(itemValue);});

Comment: Yeah I have tried this way as well. But still the issue remains. That is, when I change to different `State` (such as: _Kuala Lumpur_ to _Selangor_) the `City` value `"city": "256"` (_Puchong_) fails to load.